# Testing FTP on development machine

Tags: windows-7, ftp

I Added FTP to a site on IIS7 in windows 7 in order to test ftp operation performed by another website (also under IIS 7). The problem is that when i try to access the ftp site using my web browser and ftp://ftp.mysite.com it directs me to the real ftp site online even after adding an entry to the Host file. Is it possible to do what i am trying to achieve?

my entry in the host file looks like this:
**127.0.0.1::21   ftp.mysite.com**

Answer (score 2):

Possibly becuase your syntax is wrong. The port number should not be in the hosts file, as that file is only used for, well, hostname resolution.

```
127.0.0.1 ftp.mysite.com
```

Comment: sorry i should have mentioned that i tried every possible combinations i could think of. The one you suggested return me "server not found"

Comment: In that case, it sounds like there's most likely a configuration problem with your FTP server.

Comment: If the hosts file doesn't appear to be working, check your proxy settings.  They could be ignoring your hosts file.